# Is it possible to auto-increment getSharedPreferences name?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am a novice android programmer and am creating an app where the user can fill out a form multiple times and, later, pick from a list showing the previous entries.

The call function for sharedprefences is: `SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode);`

One idea I had was to have the user fill out a title and have that be `String name` but then I wouldn't know how to list them. So I think an array would be best that could manage itself. This would allow me to list each form using a for loop from `i = 0` to `i = lastFormFilled`

Any ideas?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is not designed for arbitrary data structures. Consider using something else (JSON file, XML file, SQLite database, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you very much for your suggestion. Do you have any suggestions of keywords I should use for my search? Or should I just search something like: `Android Data Structure Examples`

Comment: @Rayaarito Have a look at Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html this might tick all the boxes for you.